# How to activate an excelsheet without opening it in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to check a cell in another excel, if cell is bigger then "0" or not.

Is it posible to do it without opening referring excel?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with a formula, no need for VBA

Comment: I addition you may use ADODB.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use a formula:

```
=IF('C:\Path\To\Workbook\[myWorkbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1>0,"YES","NO")
```

or if you must use VBA:

```vb
Dim isGreaterThan As Boolean
'// Change the Sheet number and cell reference to match
With GetObject("C:\Path\To\Workbook\myWorkbook.xlsx")
    isGreaterThan = (CInt(.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value) > 0)
    .Close
End With

Debug.Print "Number is " & IIf(isGreaterThan,"","NOT ") & "greater than 0"
```

Comment: In the VBA version actually the workbook is opened via late binding.

Comment: It's opened in memory - but it's not activated, and it's automatically disposed of after the `End With` so it depends on the OP's definition of "open" which I'm guessing is along the lines of "a window is opened and interferes with my code"

Comment: Step into the code in debug mode. Enter `Application.Workbooks.Count` in Immediate window. Before `GetObject()` there is only 1 workbook. After `End With` there are 2 workbooks. Thus, workbook is opened, and should be closed. If not to do so, after you close Excel workbook, Excel application will be displayed with hidden workbook.

Comment: Sorry - I see what you mean, I forgot the close line - will add it in now. Good spot!

Comment: Be aware of some dialog windows that might appear while opening and closing workbook.

Answer (score 0):

As omegastripes commented this is also possible using ADO.

The following will return the value of cell A1 on sheet1 of the specified workbook.

Ensure you have set a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects X.X Library"

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strPath As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'full Path of file to check
strPath = "C:\Path\To\Workbook\myWorkbook.xlsx"

'open connection to workbook
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & strPath & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;"""

'open recordset of value(s) from specified sheet & range
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:A1];", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

'print returned value
If Not rs.EOF Then Debug.Print rs(0)

'cleanup
rs.Close
cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```